# How to use stored procedure to output all rows from Select and call another procedure?

Tags: stored-procedures, db2

I feel like I'm very close here, yet missing something that would be obvious. I'm not looking for someone to fix this for me, but to point me in the right direction, please.

I'm working with DB2 11.5.

This will create the procedure; however, it doesn't return the correct
output.

It only outputs one row, where there are several, yet it does properly update the table that `OTHER_PROCEDURE` populates with all the returned rows.

The OUT rows are handed to an automation app that iterates through the record set and performs a function with each record. With it only handing back one row, of course it can't complete its job. Yet the `OTHER_PROCEDURE` does update its table correctly.

The automation app can only call one procedure or one compound SQL statement. It can't make more than one call or call a procedure and then a SQL statement.

The expected output is several rows like;

| oRECORD_ID | oSTRING_ONE | oSTRING_TWO |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0001 | AB1234 | email@company1.com |
| 0004 | CS5555 | email@company2.com |
| 0 013 | FN4561 | email@company3.com |

The automation app loops over the record set, sending a report based on `oSTRING_ONE` to the email in `oSTRING_TWO`. However, it seems to only process one row.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE NEW_PROCEDURE(
  OUT oRECORD_ID INTEGER,
  OUT oSTRING_ONE VARCHAR(10),
  OUT oSTRING_TWO VARCHAR(80)
)

LANGUAGE SQL
SPECIFIC SP_NEW_PROCEDURE
BEGIN

  DECLARE iRECORD_ID INTEGER;
  
    DECLARE GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE SESSION.TEMP_TABLE (
      RECORD_ID INTEGER,
      STRING_ONE VARCHAR(10),
      STRING_TWO VARCHAR(80)
    ) WITH REPLACE NOT LOGGED; 

      CREATE GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE TEMP_TABLE (
      RECORD_ID INTEGER,
      STRING_ONE VARCHAR(10),
      STRING_TWO VARCHAR(80)
      );

INSERT INTO TEMP_TABLE (RECORD_ID, STRING_ONE, STRING_TWO)
SELECT T.RECORD_ID, T.STRING_ONE, C.STRING_TWO
FROM PERMANENT_TABLE T
LEFT OUTER JOIN --statement continues to get the C.STRING_TWO values. Removed for clarity yet does return the expected records.
  );
  

FOR c AS cur CURSOR FOR

    SELECT RECORD_ID, STRING_ONE, STRING_TWO
    FROM TEMP_TABLE

DO

    SET oRECORD_ID = c.RECORD_ID;
    SET oSTRING_ONE = c.STRING_ONE;
    SET oSTRING_TWO = c.STRING_TWO;

    SET iORDER_ID = c.RECORD_ID;

    CALL OTHER_PROCEDURE(iORDER_ID);

END FOR;
  
END
@
```

Comment: Seems that your automation app can process stored procedure output parameters. It this correct? Can it process a stored procedure result set returned by this SP?

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to do. Can you provide a minimum setup and what the expected output would be?

Comment: @MarkBarinstein Correct. I'm not sure if it can only handle one row or multiple rows. The app can handle multiple rows if it's a simple SQL select, but I'm not sure about the internal mechanism for handling the result set from a stored procedure. I'm trying to get more info from the app developers.

Comment: @Innertube It's worth to ask them if their app can process some "compound" output from SP as well in case, if they can't process a result set from SP. For example, you may return a LOB representation of an XML value containing n records with these 3 fields each.